# How to move Lesscss files outside the public symfony web directory?

Tags: less, twig, symfony, assetic

With Symfony 3, I'm using Assetic filters to process my `.less` files, and I simply want to know how to move them outside the `/web` directory, for example from `/web/css` to `/app/Resources/less`.

Indeed, in twig templates I don't know how to give the right location.

I'm using a basic Assetic config:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: ['/usr/local/bin/node_modules']
```

Let's say I have this simple Less file, currently located at `/web/css/test.less`:

```less
@color : orange;

body {
    background-color : @color;
}
```

Then, if I want to generate the link to the processed stylesheet, I'm doing like this in an HTML template:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        [ ... ]

        {% stylesheets 'css/test.less' filter="less" output='css/test.css' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}

    </head>
    <body> </body>
</html>
```

So, if I move `/web/css/test.less` to `/app/Resources/less/test.less`, what should I give instead the `#####` below ?

```
        {% stylesheets '#####' filter="less" output='css/test.css' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this (2nd edit):

```
{% stylesheets '@Resources/*' filter="less" output='less/test.less' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Then place your files under Resources like this:

```
Resources/less/test.less
```

Where Resources is the path 'src/AppBundle/Resources'.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it by giving the `/web` related path : `{% stylesheets '../app/Resources/less/test.less' ... %}`... But I'm not really sure it's a good practice to do like this.

Comment: You mean you moved your "app/Resources" folder under your web folder?

Comment: no, I just used the path `'../app/Resources/less/test.less'` instead of the `'#####'` given in my question

Comment: Your answer was helpful but it didn't work : `'@app/...'` returns this error : `"Bundle "app" does not exist or it is not enabled.`; and `'app/...'` doesn't find the source file. When I saw the absolute path it tried to access, I realised it was related to `/web` path.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what is happening. The '@' is a bundle path. I wonder if you could move your folder to `src/AppBundle/Resources` (create a new folder if it doesn't exist)? I'll edit my post to my suggested path.